# wp-prepare function error "Too few arguments"

Tags: wordpress

In my Wordpress plugin I have code snippets that look like this:

```
$total = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare( 

    "

        SELECT SUM(Amount) 

        FROM $table_name 

        WHERE Account = $user_id AND Timestamp > {$balance['Timestamp']}

    ",NULL

));
```

It was working very well for years, but after I recently updated Wordpress to 5.0 I get many errors like this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function wpdb::prepare(), 1 passed in (...)/pluginfile.php on line 753 and exactly 2 expected in /wp-includes/wp-db.php:1222
```

Through my research I found that I need to use `%s` and `%d` in the `wp` prepare function but I didn't figure out how to apply it properly to the code above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anybody that might run into a similar problem: with the help of the comment above by @entreprenerds I was able to fix the code as follows:

```
$total = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare( 
"
SELECT SUM(Amount) 

FROM $table_name 

WHERE Account = %d AND Timestamp > %d

",$user_id, $balance['Timestamp']
));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We use the 'prepare' method to make sure we're not sending an illegal operation or any illegal characters.

Try modifying your code to the following:

```
$total = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare(

    "
        SELECT SUM(Amount) 

        FROM $table_name 

        WHERE Account = %d AND Timestamp > %d

    ",

    $user_id, $balance['Timestamp']

));
```

Both User ID and a timestamp are integers (whole numbers) so we would use %d.

Possible format values: %s as string; %d as integer (whole number); and %f as float.

Comment: Thanks for your help!
What seemed to work was: ... WHERE Account = %d AND Timestamp > %d", $user_id, $balance['Timestamp'] ));

So for some reasons it didn't work as array() and also the {%d} ended up to make problems.
Any explanations for this?

Comment: The curly braces are for complex variable expressions. They are interpreted by PHP, not by the SQL interface. Now that we've taken the array out of the SQL statement, I guess they are no longer required. If my answer has been useful, it would be nice if you at least upvoted it :)

Comment: I did, but it says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."